# In PHP, what is the significance of setting a parameter in a function equal to true?

Tags: php, parameters

While reviewing a function in the wordpress source code I ran across a function that listed several parameters as such

```
function mysql2date( $dateformatstring, $mysqlstring, $translate = true )
```

My question revolves around the final parameter "$translate = true"
Is this setting the variable to true, or only calling $translate IF it is equal to true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a default value. If the paramater is provided when calling the function, the value of `$translate` within the function will be whatever value was passed in. If not, it will default to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

This means that the third parameter `$translate` will be *optional* and will default to `true` if that parameter isn't provided when the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

It's a default value, setting it to true